# Dynamically change content on rcarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I am using "rcarousel – a continuous jQuery UI carousel" located at http://ryrych.github.io/rcarousel/.  After creating the carousel, I wish to change the content on one of the carousel panes.  I could change the content easily enough with the following script: `$('#carousel').find('input.change').click(function(){$(this).parent().parent().find('div.display').html('New content');});`

Problem is if you go to another pane, then back, the "changed" pane reverts back to it's original content.

A live example is located at http://tapmeister.com/test/ryrych-rcarousel/examples/dynamic.php, and the script is included below.

```
var active=true;

$("#carousel").rcarousel(
    {
        visible: 1,
        step: 1,
        width: 780,
        height: 240,
        speed: 500,
        startAtPage: 2,
        start: function() {
            var carousel=$(this),parent=carousel.parent();
            $('#next-slide').click(function(){if(active) {carousel.rcarousel("next");}});
            $('#prev-slide').click(function(){if(active) {carousel.rcarousel("prev");}});

            for ( var i = 0; i < carousel.rcarousel( "getTotalPages" ); i++ ) {
                $("<a />",{href:'#','class':'carousel-bullet off'})
                .bind("click", {page: i},
                    function( event ) {
                        if(active) {
                            carousel.rcarousel( "goToPage", event.data.page );
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }
                )
                .appendTo( "#carousel-pages" );
            }

            // mark first page as active
            $( "a:eq(0)", "#carousel-pages" )
            .removeClass( "off" )
            .addClass( "on" )
            .css("background-image", "url(images/page-on.png)" );

            $("#next-slide, #prev-slide, .carousel-bullet" )
            .hover(
                function(){
                    if(active){$( this ).css("opacity", 0.7 );}
                },
                function(){
                    if(active){$( this ).css("opacity", 1.0 );}
                }
            );

        },
        pageLoaded: function( event, data ) {
            $( "a.on", "#carousel-pages" )
            .removeClass( "on" )
            .css("background-image", "url(images/page-off.png)" );

            $( "a", "#carousel-pages" )
            .eq( data.page )
            .addClass( "on" )
            .css("background-image", "url(images/page-on.png)" );
        }

    }
);

<div id="carousel-container">
    <div id="carousel">

        <div class="slide">
            <div class="sub-slide">
                <img src="images/throbber.gif" class="throbber" alt="Please Wait" />
                <div class="display">Display 0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <input class="change" type="button" value="change">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="sub-slide">
                <img src="images/throbber.gif" class="throbber" alt="Please Wait" />
                <div class="display">Display 1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <input class="change" type="button" value="change">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="sub-slide">
                <img src="images/throbber.gif" class="throbber" alt="Please Wait" />
                <div class="display">Display 2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <input class="change" type="button" value="change">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="sub-slide">
                <img src="images/throbber.gif" class="throbber" alt="Please Wait" />
                <div class="display">Display 3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <input class="change" type="button" value="change">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="sub-slide">
                <img src="images/throbber.gif" class="throbber" alt="Please Wait" />
                <div class="display">Display 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <input class="change" type="button" value="change">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="sub-slide">
                <img src="images/throbber.gif" class="throbber" alt="Please Wait" />
                <div class="display">Display 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <input class="change" type="button" value="change">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <a href="#" id="next-slide" class="change-slide"></a>
    <a href="#" id="prev-slide" class="change-slide"></a>
    <div id="carousel-pages"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you inspect the HTML of the carousel and tell us if the `pane` has any `data-` attributes that hold reference to `the content`? If you find out it does, simply target that data- attribute and replace what's in it. If not, then you'll need to re-instantiate the plugin.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy.  When inspecting with Firebug, no attributes are shown.  Did notice, however, that only current pane is included in HTML.  How would you recommend inspecting the HTML?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following `updatePageDOM()` method to the plugin

```
updatePageDOM: function() {
    var $root = $(this.element),
    data=$root.data("data");
    //Note that data.paths[data.pageIndex] and data.pages[data.pageIndex][0] is the same
    data.paths[data.pageIndex].html($root.find('div.slide').html());
},
```